# Java Client Errors

Tags: java

I've been learning inheritance and working on a project that deals with a parent class Athlete and child class HockeyPlayer. When I compile, it says it cannot find symbol when I call setGoals in my client:

```
    Athlete hockey = new HockeyPlayer();
    hockey.setGoals(10);
```

and the following is the code from  HockeyPlayer class:

```
public class HockeyPlayer extends Athlete
{
    private int goals, number;
    private String team;

    public HockeyPlayer()
    {
        super();  //sets name, age, and salary from Athlete constructor
        goals = 0;
        number = 0;
        team = "";
    }

    public void setGoals(int goals)
    {
        this.goals = goals;
    } 
}
```

Any input on how I can fix this error?

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace along with the code for the `Athlete` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hockey is an Athlete not a HockeyPlayer.  You can only call methods defined for Athlete unless you cast it to a HockeyPlayer.

Comment: Much appreciated! forgot I had to do that when dealing with inheritance